# iOS where is applicationWillEnterBackground defined? when is it called?

Tags: ios, xcode, protocols, lifecycle

Probably a novice question: I'm working with some legacy code that has an implementation for

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

There's no explicit definition of this method in the headers, so I assumed it's part of the adopted protocol (UIApplicationDelegate) however it's not included in apple's documentation.

Is this method called as a part of the app life-cycle? (Afterall the method's name closely resembles applicationDidEnterBackground which is listed as a UIApplicationDelegate method)

If it is part of the life-cycle when is it called?

Comment: At the time of asking this question I assumed that all implemented methods must have a corresponding declaration in the header file, with the only exception being inherited/adopted methods. This is of course not true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `applicationWillEnterBackground` doesn't occur in the `UIKit` dynamic library.  I'm pretty sure the system never sends that message.

```
:; strings - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit | grep applicationWillEnterBackground
```

For comparison, the library does contain the string `applicationDidEnterBackground`:

```
:; strings - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit | grep applicationDidEnterBackground
applicationDidEnterBackground:
_applicationDidEnterBackground:
-[UIActivityIndicatorView _applicationDidEnterBackground:]
```